# Pandas rounds number to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign a value to a cell, yet Pandas rounds it to zero. (I'm using Python 3.6)

```
in: df['column1']['row1'] = 1 / 331616

in: print(df['column1']['row1'])

out: 0
```

But if I try to assign this value to a standard Python dictionary key, it works fine.

```
in: {'column1': {'row1': 1/331616}}

out: {'column1': {'row1': 3.0155360416867704e-06}}
```

I've already done this, but it didn't help:

- pd.set_option('precision',50)
- pd.set_option('chop_threshold',
  .00000000005)

Please, help.

Comment: What version of python? If it's python2, you need to cast one of those operands to `float`: `df['column1']['row1'] = 1.0 / 331616`

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: @AlexeyYunoshev Did you try changing `1` to `1.0` as what pault recommended?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I did. Didn't help

Comment: What are the types of each column?  Type in `df.dtypes` into the interpreter and see what you get.  I'm betting that it's `int` or some variant of it.

Comment: Yes, it's int64. Is that a problem?

Comment: It is, it should be float64. Try to convert your column using `pd.Series.astype(float)` maybe

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much, good sirs.

Comment: @AlexeyYunoshev You're welcome.  The reason why it rounded to 0 was because the native data type of the column was `int64` so division results in truncation.  You need to convert to floating point before you do so.  In Python 3, doing vanilla division automatically provides a floating point result, but not in Pandas if the column type is `int`.  That's why replicating the results in a dictionary had different results than doing it within the dataframe.

Comment: @rayryeng Good to know that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column's datatype most likely is set to `int`.  You'll need to either convert it to `float` or mixed types `object` before assigning the value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6])

df.dtypes
# 0    int64
# dtype: object

df[0][4] = 7/125

df
#    0
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
# 3  4
# 4  0
# 5  6

df[0] = df[0].astype('O')

df[0][4] = 7 / 22
df

#           0
# 0         1
# 1         2
# 2         3
# 3         4
# 4  0.318182
# 5         6

df.dtypes

# 0    object
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. People in the comments above have already helped me to figure it out. Hopefully, your answer will help someone else. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, yes I realized that after the fact, but since it's all typed out I'll just leave it here.  May the rest of your code be bugless and clean.  Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

pandas appears to be presuming that your datatype is an `integer (int)`.

There are several ways to address this, either by setting the datatype to a `float` when the DataFrame is constructed OR by changing (or casting) the datatype (also referred to as a `dtype`) to a `float` on the fly.

## setting the datatype (dtype) during construction:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
```

In making this simple DataFrame, we provide a single example value (`1`) and the columns for the DataFrame are defined as containing `floats` during creation

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1]], columns=['column1'], index=['row1'], dtype=float)
>>> df['column1']['row1'] = 1 / 331616
>>> df
       column1
row1  0.000003
```

## converting the datatype on the fly:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1]], columns=['column1'], index=['row1'], dtype=int)
>>> df['column1'] = df['column1'].astype(float)
>>> df['column1']['row1'] = 1 / 331616
df
       column1
row1  0.000003
```